# Exporting from Ephesoft Comunity to Alfresco using CMIS plugin

Tags: plugins, integration, alfresco, cmis, ephesoft

I was following this tuto , here's the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JXQdDoQCCU but i have no access to https://my.alfresco.com/share.

if there is no way , i need another solution to export to alfresco automatically .

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to the Alfresco cloud-hosted version? Why aren't you connecting to your own local Alfresco  install?

Comment: that tuto is all what i found , can you help me please , i wasted a month searching how to export to alfresco .

Comment: https://tpeelen.wordpress.com/2010/12/23/configuring-ephesoft-and-alfresco-for-cmis-integration/  should i follow this ? @Gagravarr .

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the version of Alfresco you're connecting to, you'll need to configure the CMIS Export to hit the appropriate CMIS endpoint for your Alfresco instance. Assuming it's an Alfresco 4.2+ instance (using CMIS 1.1), that endpoint will look like this:

```
http://<hostname>:<port>/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom
```

If it's using CMIS 1.0 (pre-4.2), it will look like this:

```
http://<hostname>:<port>/alfresco/cmisatom
```

If it's CMIS 1.1, you'll use the "-default-" CMIS Repository ID. If it's CMIS 1.0, provide your repository ID.

You'll then need to provide the credentials for the Alfresco instance.

Also make sure you turn "ON" the CMIS Server switch.

Set the appropriate CMIS version. Also set the CMIS Root folder Name. The default behavior is to create the folder in the root of your repository.

Many of the remaining properties do not need to be set - you won't need CMIS Export Client Key, Secret Key, Refresh Token, Redirect URL, or Network to export to Alfresco.

Comment: Documentation on the CMIS export can be found here: http://wiki.ephesoft.com/cmis-export-plugin-3